# what is different between model.fit and train_test_split?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

When we train models, we should make train data, validation data, and test data to get better result.

I know that split data is easiest way to make train data, and test data(can use as validation data). We can split data with 2 ways, one is automatic way such as `model.fit(validation_split)` or `train_test_split()`, and the other way is split by array slicing.

I'm confused about `model.fit(validation_split)` and `train_test_split()`. Is it different between `model.fit(validation_split)` and `train_test_split()`?

I think that `train_test_split()` use same splited data regardless of the epoch progress, but `model.fit(validation_split)` is confused. `model.fit(validation_split)` splits data every each epoches? or splits data only once?

Thanks for reading.

#adding example codes

```
#for example about model.fit(validation_split)
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add( some layers)
model.complie()
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs = 10000, batch_size=batchSize, validation_split=0.2) #this is model.fit(validation_split)


#for example about train_test_split()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xTrain, x_val, yTrain, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)# this is train_test_split()

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add( some layers)
model.complie()
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs = 10000, batch_size=batchSize, validation_data=(x_val, y_val)) #cannot use model.fit(validation_split and validation_data) at once
```

Comment: The fit method is used for building weights while doing the training , one should never run fit method on test data.Also, to split data at random, one should use train_test_split. I am not seeing any code, so i am guessing based on my understanding. Please show the code in context to answer it better. Thanks

Comment: @PKumar Thanks for your help. Now, I add some codes to explane the methods about spliting data

Comment: Please check if the following answers your question:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38955/how-does-the-validation-split-parameter-of-keras-fit-function-work

Comment: @AndreasKaufmann Thanks for letting me know what I couldn't find. It helps a lot.